# WebdriverIO - Running tests in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, automated-tests, gitlab-ci-runner, webdriver-io, wdio-v6

I am trying to run my tests in the gitlab pipeline and I keep getting the same error:

Here is my yml:

```
    stages:
      - setup
      - test
    setup:
      stage: setup
      image: node:latest
      services:
        - name: selenium/standalone-chrome
          alias: selenium
      script:
        - |
          cat << EOF > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
          deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
          EOF
        - wget -O- https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub |gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google.gpg
        - apt update
        - apt install -y google-chrome-stable
        - google-chrome --version
        - npm install
    test:
      stage: test  
      image: node:latest
      script:
        - npm run pipelineQA
        - npm run report  
        - allure generate -c ./allure-results -o ./allure-report
      artifacts:
        when: always
        paths:
          - /allure-report
          - /allure-results
        expire_in: 1 week
```

this is the error:
[gitlab error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FF0B.png)

Also how do I get allure to save and display my reports